# Flash Actionscript 3 saving a XML file locally has a "Save As" window (How can I remove it?)

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

So, I have a flash application that handles several client profiles for a company. Whenever a new client profile is created, it saves a new XML file localy. My problem is that instead of doing a "silent" file creation, a window pops up just like doing a "Save As" as to confirm that the file is being saved on disk and which name should it be.

Is there a way to do a file save within flash without it calling out that window? If so, would it be possible to link me to an example of it?

Here is an example of my code:

```
var xmltosave:XML = new XML ( "<?xml version=&quot1.0&quot encoding=&quotutf-8&quot?><cliente><id>"+idfield.text+"</id><nome>"+nomefield.text+"</nome><tipo>"+tipofield.text+"</tipo><empresa></empresa><email>"+emailfield.text+"</email><contacto>"+contacto1field.text+"</contacto><contacto2>"+contacto2field.text+"</contacto2><profissao></profissao><datainscricao>"+datafield.text+"</datainscricao><dataalteracao></dataalteracao><notas></notas><notas2></notas2><notas3></notas3></cliente>");

var file:FileReference = new FileReference;
var filepath:String = new String(idfield.text + ".xml");
file.save( xmltosave, filepath );
```

Also, I know that the xmltosave is very long, is it possible to do line breaks in AS3 code?

Thank you.
Marco Roberto.

NOTE: I know that I should use a php script to manage files, but unless that php is able to run locally without any server installs, like XAMPP, im not interested in using it. This is a small project and I just need to handle XML files. Unless its absolutely impossible to do it without PHP scripts, I would prefer a AS3 solution.

Comment: Is this a web application or desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're building a desktop application you can use [flash.filesystem.File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html), which is part of the AIR SDK, to save files as a background process.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm not familiar with AIR, can I implement it in my flash application without having to mess around too much with the code?

Comment: the File class requires AIR.  i assumed you were programming with AIR since you were building an application with ActionScript 3.0 for desktop.  how are you creating your desktop application?  are you simply distributing a standalone .swf file?

Comment: Yes. It does have a explanation, however. It started as a web application using php, but since im a newby programmer, I couldn't handle a lot of the stuff in php. Then my boss said there would be no problem in using XML files to have a stand alone local program, as long as it was working properly. Thus I decided to switch to XML. I know, its a bit messy.