# Saving an XML file using AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way of actually saving this as an XML file itself to then be read into the flash file separately?

```
var book:XML = <book/>;
book.publisher = <publisher/>;
book.publisher.@name ="O'Reilly";

book.title = "Learning ActionScript 3.0";

book.appendChild(<subject/>);
book.subject.prependChild("Action Script");
book.insertChildAfter(book.subject, <authors/>);

book.authors.author.firstname = "Zevan";
book.authors.author.lastname = "Rosser";

var tempList:XMLList = book.authors.author.copy()
tempList[0].firstname = "Rich"
tempList[0].lastname = "Shupe"
book.authors.insertChildBefore(book.authors.author, tempList);

trace (book);
```

Comment: What is the platform?  AIR?  Browser?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, in fact there's already a question on stack overflow that had and adequate answer, you could check: [Flash Actionscript 3 saving a XML file locally has a "Save As" window (How can I remove it?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379649/flash-actionscript-3-saving-a-xml-file-locally-has-a-save-as-window-how-can-i) .
Any way, you could do it using AIR as flash has a library that will help you save files as a background process, you can find all the informations you need here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon on StackOverflow. If you feel like the question is a duplicate, flag it as such and leave a comment referring the person to the answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can save this as an `xml`. and read in flash. store it locally and use shared object. check [this link](http://as3gametuts.com/2012/02/28/actionscript-saving-and-loading-tutorial/) for reference.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon on StackOverflow.  If the only thing you can contribute is a link,  give it as a comment or as a reference for a real answer.    Otherwise, make your answer much more useful by providing an example.

Comment: @LDMS I had given a special link before it was edited but anw thanks i'll think of it next time :)